# How to unit-test `mergeMap()` function in ngrx/effects using ReplaySubject()?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngrx-effects

I am writing unit-test for Angular ngrx/effects, for a todo app.
I am using ReplaySubject() as they are more intuitive and easy to test, instead of jasmine marbels (hot and cold).

But i am getting following error.

```js
    should dispatch success and error actions for AddTodoItem
        HeadlessChrome 74.0.3729 (Linux 0.0.0)
        Error: Expected object to be a kind of AddTodoItemSuccess, but was LoadTodos({ type: '[Todo] Load Todos' }).
            at <Jasmine>
            at SafeSubscriber._next (src/app/store/effects/app.effects.spec.ts:46:24)
            at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:183:1)
            at SafeSubscriber.next (node_modules/rxjs/_esm2015/internal/Subscriber.js:122:1)
```

**App.effects.ts**

```ts
@Effect()
  loadTodos$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromTodos.LoadTodos>(TodoActionTypes.LOAD_TODOS),
    switchMap((action) => {
      return this.todoService.getTodos().pipe(
        map(data => {
          return new fromTodos.LoadTodosSuccess(data);
        }),
        catchError(err => of(new fromTodos.LoadTodosFailure(err)))
      );
    })
  );

  @Effect()
  addTodo$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromTodos.AddTodoItem>(TodoActionTypes.ADD_TODO_ITEM),
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.todoService.addTodo(action.payload).pipe(
        mergeMap(data => {
          return [new fromTodos.AddTodoItemSuccess(data),  new fromTodos.LoadTodos()];
        }),
        catchError(err => of(new fromTodos.AddTodoItemFailure(err)))
      );
    })
  );
```

**app.effects.spec.ts**

```ts
describe('AppEffects', () => {
  let actions$: ReplaySubject<any>;
  let effects: AppEffects;
  const testTodo: Todo = {
    id: 0,
    todo: 'string',
    mark_as_done: true,
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AppEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions$)
      ]
    });

    effects = TestBed.get(AppEffects);
  });

  // passsing
  it('should dispatch success and error actions for LoadTodos', () => {
    actions$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    actions$.next(new fromActions.LoadTodos());

    effects.loadTodos$.subscribe(
      result => expect(result).toEqual(new fromActions.LoadTodosSuccess(null), 'should dispatch'),
      err => expect(err).toEqual(new fromActions.LoadTodosFailure(null))
    );
  });

  // failing
  it('should dispatch success and error actions for AddTodoItem', () => {
    actions$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    actions$.next(new fromActions.AddTodoItem(testTodo));

    effects.addTodo$.subscribe(
      result => { console.log('AddTodoItem', result);
        expect(result).toEqual(new fromActions.AddTodoItemSuccess(undefined), new fromActions.LoadTodos());
      },
      err => expect(err).toEqual(new fromActions.AddTodoItemFailure(err))
    );
  });
});
```

**Screenshot of error**

[image: error screenshot]

---

I referred to ngrx documentation, but it did not have any example of mergeMap. **How to write the test for effects where multiple actions are dispatched using mergeMap**?

Comment: i have done `console.log()` of result, to see whats happening, i could see two actions are dispatched at different time. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/5XpzSUA.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out, thanks @timdeschryver for hints.

You need `take` and `skip` operators of rxjs to test if the first and second actions are dispatched as expected.

- take(2) takes only first 2 events of the observable
- skip(2) skips the first 2 events of observable

**app.effects.ts**

```js
  @Effect()
  addTodo$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<fromTodos.AddTodoItem>(TodoActionTypes.ADD_TODO_ITEM),
    switchMap(action => {
      return this.todoService.addTodo(action.payload).pipe(
        mergeMap(data => {
          return [new fromTodos.AddTodoItemSuccess(data), new fromTodos.LoadTodos()];
        }),
        catchError(err => of(new fromTodos.AddTodoItemFailure(err)))
      );
    })
  );
```

**app.effets.spec.ts**

```js
  it('should dispatch success and error actions for AddTodoItem', () => {
    actions$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
    actions$.next(new fromActions.AddTodoItem(testTodo));

    effects.addTodo$
          .pipe(take(1))  // this takes only the first event of the observable
          .subscribe(
            result => expect(result).toEqual(new fromActions.AddTodoItemSuccess(undefined), 'first action should be AddTodoItemSuccess'),
            err => expect(err).toEqual(new fromActions.AddTodoItemFailure(err))
          );

    effects.addTodo$
          .pipe(skip(1))  // this skips the first event of observable, and takes from second event (i.e. the second action alone will be available now)
          .subscribe(
            result => expect(result).toEqual(new fromActions.LoadTodos(), 'second action should be LoadTodos'),
            err => expect(err).toEqual(new fromActions.AddTodoItemFailure(err))
          );
  });
```

Comment: The only working 2022 answer here, thank you, Raj. Do you know why don't we put ReplaySubject assignment in the outer describe block?

Comment: @MaximeLyakhov If we keep it outside, and let all tests use the same, ideally it should not conflict. Hmm....That's a gud one,  something to explore.

Answer (score 1):

Your effect returns two actions `new fromTodos.AddTodoItemSuccess(data), new fromTodos.LoadTodos()`.

In your test you use `expect(result).toEqual(new fromActions.LoadTodos(), new fromActions.AddTodoItemSuccess(undefined));`, which checks if the action returned is `LoadTodos.` Because the second action returned is the success action, we still verify if the action is the `LoadTodos` action, resulting in the error.

Comment: Hi tim, thanks for checking this question. What you are suggesting is to reverse the order of actions in spec file `AddTodoItemSuccess` then `LoadTodos`. I already tried that, didn't work. [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/U7Voqiu.png)

Comment: Is it possible for you to suggest the correct syntax of the `expect` statement? testing that mergeMap??

Comment: Not reversing the order, but you would want to check if the first action that is dispatched is the Success action, the second action to be the Load action.

Comment: Ok, i understood, thanks for the hint. I just learnt about `take` and `skip` rxjs operator. that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is order of returned value in `loadTodo$` effect:

```
[new fromTodos.AddTodoItemSuccess(data), new fromTodos.LoadTodos()]
```

and this is your assertion:

```
expect(result).toEqual(new fromActions.LoadTodos(), new fromActions.AddTodoItemSuccess(undefined));
```

even error tolds you about that:

```
Expected object to be kind of LoadTodos, but was AddTodoItemSuccess...
```

*Edit1*

Second argument in `toEqual` method is `expectationFailOutput` which is short info that you would like to output when assertion fails. Note that in `subscribe` body you firstly get `AddTodoItemSuccess` and then `LoadTodos` - not at once. Probably this is reason why test fails.

Comment: I corrected my order of actions, still the same error.  [error screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/U7Voqiu.png)